# Convert SQL query into Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need to convert this query into laravel query builder

```
select * from employee where(( age = 25 and salary = 20000) or (age =30 and salary = 30000))
```

Comment: what is your current attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
$data = Model::where([["age", "25"],["salary", "20000"]])
    ->orWhere([["age", "30"],["salary", "30000"]])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group where clauses you can nest them inside closures:

```
DB::table('employee')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('age', 25)->where('salary', 20000);
    })
    ->orWHere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('age', 30)->where('salary', 30000);
    })
    ->get();
```

For more information have a look at [Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping)  in the documentation.

Comment: can you please give me a reference or documentation link for this?